# Filezilla server file unable to FTP. putting blank "/ /filename"

Tags: filezilla

I am having an issue using filezilla server to import a file. This is the following error I have. The file is being sent in passive mode if it has anything to do with it?

error message:

150 opening data channel for file upload to server of "/ /vertique_product_113"

550 can't access file

Has anyone ever seen it try to put an empty "/ /" in the file path?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. YOu say you're using filezilla *server* to upload the file. Normally, the server is the *recipient* of the file and you connect to it with an FTP client (including filezilla client).

I'm going to answer the question "why is (this) happening when I try to upload a file using filezilla client."

Before you can use Filezilla client to move files around, you create a "site" entry (with the "New Site" button in the control-s dialog). By any chance did you enter the Host name by copy and paste from a browser's location bar?

The reason I ask is that a typical URL has the form:
    https://fully-qualified-host-name/filename
So if you accidentally copied the "//" prefix into the dialog, your client will try to open a host named `"//vertique_product_11"` instead of `"vertique_product_11"`.

You should also look at "Settings" under the "Edit" menu and see if there's anything suspicious there.

If, on the other hand, this really *is* occurring on the server side, then either the client is sending a bad string or the server is misconfigured. I've never installed the server, so I can't give much help on that side except to say you should examine your server configuration file (or the dialogs that let you manage it) for an unexpected //.

Comment: you are correct, the server was the recipient. I have a feeling the third party company was sending me a bad string. However, I degraded my version of FileZilla server and it worked correctly. So I may never fully understand the solution to this problem. The thrid party company tells me that there is no / / in their path string, and that it is the same code they use to send me other files which work correctly. Thanks for your help though.